Traversable functor with product of two applicatives in Scala
I have been trying to traverse a data structure in Scala and do two things at the same time. I have been using Cats library for this. Here's a little example which does not compile. I do not understand how I could make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated.
import cats.data.Tuple2K
import cats.data.Const
import cats.syntax.traverse._

List("A", "BB", "CCC").traverse[Tuple2K[[x] =>> Const[Int, x], [x] =>> Const[Int, x], Nothing], Nothing]{
 case str => 
   Tuple2K[[x] =>> Const[Int, x], [x] =>> Const[Int, x], Nothing](Const(1), Const(str.size)) 
} 

The tools throw the following error:
Found:    cats.data.Tuple2K[[x] =>> cats.data.Const[Int, x], [x] =>> cats.data.Const[Int, x], Nothing]     
Required: cats.data.Tuple2K[[x] =>> cats.data.Const[Int, x], [x] =>> cats.data.Const[Int, x], Nothing][Nothing]    
I am trying to get both the size of the traversable (the above list in my example) and perform some content based computations in one traversal only, as opposed to traverse the list twice.
Update
Following the initial responses to my post, I decided to offer a bit more clarity through this update.
To be clear, if I remove the explicit type parameters, the code compiles and does what I expect it to do:
import cats.data.Tuple2K
import cats.data.Const
import cats.syntax.traverse._

List("A", "BB", "CCC").traverse{
  case str =>
    Tuple2K[[x] =>> Const[Int, x], [x] =>> Const[Int, x], Nothing](Const(1), Const(str.size))
} // Tuple2K(Const(3),Const(6)) which is of type Tuple2K[[x >: Nothing <: Any] => Const[Int, x], [x >: Nothing <: Any] => Const[Int, x], List[Nothing]] !!! 

My problem with the initial code snippet is that those types are the ones that are inferred by the compiler anyway, so passing them explicitly should just work.

Tuple2K is a product of two functors, not a functor on its own, the error says in English. Maybe there is a functor defined somewhere in cats, but why so much trouble in the first place. Why not just return a regular Tuple (not functorial one). Applicative syntax is good in Haskell, not scala.

Also you’re asking the size of string in there not of the whole collection. My previous comment assumes you want a size of element of list (string), not of a list itself. No point in attempting to use “applicative” functorial Tuple if one operation is converting an element of list to a constant and another is the size of the whole list (according to your description). If you actually want that, then use traverse without Tuple2K, it makes no sense otherwise. Traversal should be separate then, after which you can make a regular Tuple of resulting list and size.

Thank you all for the responses. Reading them made me realise I was not very clear with what I am trying to solve, which is getting the type parameters passed directly to .traverse() right. I will update the post with hopefully a bit more clarification. Thank you again for your support.

Don’t have time to look, but I think you have to mention (require) functors, applicatives and other implicit classes explicitly, a-la ‘F: Functor’, or even ‘implicit ev: Functor[_]’. Type signatures scala reports don’t include type-classes and other implicits.

But again, even if collection doesn’t have .size, it is still not physically slower to ‘(col.map(_.length).sum, col.map(const(1)).sum)’ than ‘col.map(x => (1, x.length).sum’ (assuming semigroups on Tuple and integers), same amount of operations. In practice, applicative abstractions are rarely useful too (above is much shorter, clear and concise, only requires a functor ‘.map’, catawhatever aggregation ‘.fold’ and semigroup ‘+’).

For most practical purposes (exporting a library), you can define your own functors and such, there are ten functions tops (pluses, minuses, and SQL-like operations .map, .filter, .fold). Monads are useless. For most product-oriented code, it is just more practical to avoid abstractions all together and operate with something concrete (they only useful for exporting libraries). Most of category theory is overthought mental gymnastics.

Tupesafety is useless, it meant to ensure termination, aka absence of infinite recursion (read lambda calculus vs STLC). 100% coverage test ensures it ex-machina. Too much price to pay for that by getting lost in type-ascriptions, especially since you have to do coverage test anyway for production code.

I really don't understand why are you trying to specify all those types yourself by hand. The whole point of type inference is to avoid specifying these kind of repetitive and annoying type and still be typesafe.
Anyways the type signature you want is this:
List("A", "BB", "CCC").traverse[[x] =>> Tuple2K[[y] =>> Const[Int, y], [y] =>> Const[Int, y], x], Nothing] {
 case str => 
   Tuple2K[[x] =>> Const[Int, x], [x] =>> Const[Int, x], Nothing](Const(1), Const(str.size)) 
}

That is because traverse requires two types a type constructor G[_] of kind * -> * and a normal type B of kind *.
In this case your G[_] is:
[x] =>> Tuple2K[
  [y] =>> Const[Int, y],
  [y] =>> Const[Int, y],
  x
]


You can see the code running here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/byuGYrQUTaC4HvXYA8WhNw/3

Thank you so much for responding above! Is there any chance I could ask you to explain how you inferred that traverse  type constructor G[_] needs to be of kind * -> *, and B of kind * ?

Literally by their names. F[_] is the way in the language to say that F has kind * -> * otherwise a plain name always has kind *
